# Null coalesce for unsubscribing from an event

Tags: c#, .net, events, event-handling

Null coalescing allows for some cleaner syntax in many cases.

But I just ran into the following when trying to unsubscribe from an event:

```
consumer?.Received -= Consumer_Received;
```

For which VS tells me:

> The event 'EventingBasicConsumer.Received' can only appear on the left hand side of += or -=

So, it seems I have to resort to the uglier:

```
if(consumer != null) consumer.Received -= Consumer_Received
```

Or is there some other, clean, alternative?